# UITableView not calling cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I am trying to create a view controller with a map as the header (working), but my tableview will not populate and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is never getting called. Any suggestions?

Code is on a gist here: https://gist.github.com/ohwutup/5229232
Here are some screenshots of my IB settings:
[image: UITableView]
[image: File's Owner]

Comment: Is it that the delegate and data source of the table view are set to the table view itself? Or what's "Table..." on the screenshot?

Comment: yeah. and by that question, i can already tell im doing something wrong :/

Answer (score 1):

In your `viewDidLoad` method, add this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.title = @"Nearby";

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = _mapView;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    ...
}
```

Comment: that doesnt work either. i got it working by calling [_tableview reloadData] in my completion block of my AFJSONRequestOperation

Comment: In any time of your code you need call [self.tableView reloadData], but is necessary that the UITableView knows were class is the "delegate and dataSource" of your table. In this case is DOViewController class.

Comment: Now I see in your code that you miss the use of '@syntetize' for all of your '@property' s. like '@sintetyze tableview = _tableView;'

Comment: @synthesize is not necessary these days.

Answer (score 1):

needed to do `[self reloadData]` in the completion block of my json request.

Answer (score 0):

Your tableview's datasource and delegate should be your view controller, DOViewController.  Then you tableview will populate correctly.  Change the outlets in IB to point to your view controller class.

Comment: when i do that, i get an issue that `A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time!`